# Why isn't the scope of the property of this class visiblein PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql, scope

I've written a class to create an objet to connect to a database postgres by PHP scripting, but I've a problem.

After I create an object $db = new PostgreSQL(host, port, name, user, password) I try to invoke the method connetti() to Database, but always I receve this error:

"Unable to connect to postgreSQL server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied in C.... on line 23"

here the code:

```
class PostgreSQL
{
    public $db;
    public $conn;
    public $res;

    function __contruct($host, $port, $name, $user, $password)
    {
        $db_host= "host=".$host; 
        $db_port= "port=".$port; 
        $db_name= "dbname=".$name; 
        $db_user= "user=".$user; 
        $db_password= "password=".$password;
        $this->db = $db_host." ".$db_port." ".$db_name." ".$db_user." ".$db_password; (this is the line 23)
     }

    // effettua una connessione al database selezionato
    public function connetti()
        {   
            $this->conn = pg_connect($this->db) or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

            if  (!$this->conn) {
                 return "problema di connessione";
             }

        }
```

...

I notice that if I put a string with the data for connection beneath the method connetti() everything works well. It seems a problem of scope, but this is strange, cause I know that every proprerty in the object has a global scope.

Can everyone tell me why I have this problem?

Comment: Why are you using public properties? Those should be private, or at the very least protected. There are other items that are "wrong" with your function too, but I won't go into those here. Best practice would be a better term.

Comment: The were protected, I put them public to debug.

Comment: When you construct a new object, you're positive you're passing in a valid password and not something like an empty string?

Comment: Barring the obvious SQL injection vulnerabilities, where are you actually setting the password?

Comment: In a include file in the page who response to AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to your code nor scope problem.

According to the error message, that's something relates to pgsql settings:

https://serverfault.com/questions/51140/to-get-php-communicate-with-postgresql

Comment: He's already supplying the password. It's replying with a message saying he isn't, not that it's wrong.

Comment: Yeah but I can't understand if I use the string with all the data, in method connetti() everything works property.

Comment: The strange think is that when I put a $this->db="host=......." beneath the method connetti() everything works property.

In the file where I use the classes I call them in this way:

    require_once("class.Persona.php");
    require_once("class.PostgreSQL.php");
    require_once("db_resource.php");

where db_resource.php has all values for property connection.

I define variables in there to create an istance to PostgreSQL class:

    $db = new PostgreSQL($host, $port, $dbname, $user, $password);

Comment: Try putting `echo $this->db;die;` at the first line of your `connetti()` method and see whats the output

Comment: I can't do this, cause is an AJAX call anyway I changed in the pg_dba.conf the Method from md5 to trust, now there's a new error type:

Fatal error: the administrator role doesn't exist.

Comment: I create an account Administrator (the same name of my Windows 7 account) and a database Administrator in according with error messages got, after that everything is ok, but when I try not including the resource.php (where values for connecting to database are stored) everything works well anyway.

This is very strange. I can't explain this...